# How to find and parse out data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column that has a bunch of random comment data in it. I need to parse out some specific things that are in this column. Here is a sample of one of the rows.

> Effective: 07/01/2020 Seller Type: Dealer 9 Month Premium | Inventory = 220 Promo Intro Rate = $5.00 Budget Cap = $15.00 (Fixed $5.00 + Variable $10.00) Months 1-3 = $1,100.00 (inventory X intro) Months 4-9 (varies) = $1,100.00 fixed - $3,300.00 budget cap Additional Fulfillment Details TBD: See BB/KB for questions!

One other thing to note is that each comment row is different and the information isn't all uniform and in the same order or contains the same data even.

I need to parse out the "Budget cap" rate and the base rate which is $1,100 in this case into 2 extra columns. Any ideas on how to do this would be very appreciated.

Comment: best way is to use a more strucutred language fir this like json. even better that column could be a table with columns.  that being said processing strings its not easy

Comment: This is not that easy with SQL. Personally I'd write a small application and apply regex on the values. Honestly doing this on Excel might be easier as well!

Comment: Just to highlight your problem. How does any code you write know that the first "attribute" (Effective) is "07/01/2020" and not "07/01/2020 Seller"? How does it know that the second attribute is known as "Seller Type" versus "Type"? Hope you see where this is going.

Comment: Good question,and yes i see where that is going. When you export to csv file, and put it in an excel file, it separated them because there is a "BOX" symbol in between. does that help? it is a field inside of our CRM(MS Dynamics) where the Sales reps just type this in. as im sure you can tell, im pretty new to SQL query and code writing in general.

Comment: i didn't think that you could use REGEX in MSSQL? and if you could, how would that work exactly?

Comment: @EVANMALONE SQL Server does not support Regex, they are recommending that you write code in another language like Python or C# for example, and parse it using those types of languages are usually a better fit for this type of task.

Comment: @EVANMALONE what do you mean by a "BOX" symbol? Also, if this field is hand typed by users, you honestly should just stop here, go back to the source of this data, and work with them to see if it's possible to construct something usable. You may be driven to solve this particular challenge, but it will be a MASSIVE pain to maintain the code over time. I am speaking from experience on this one. If this code is breaking all the time because the shape of the data keeps changing it's going to be on you, even though it's a ridiculous task to solve in the first place.